# To what depth can I lower this tube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, bubbles

This is a problem I came across: Imagine there is a glass test-tube with a small hole of radius ‘r’ at the bottom of the tube. Now this tube is lowered into a water-filled beaker; upto what depth ‘d’ can you lower the test-tube into the water before water starts filling into the test-tube through the hole? Given that the surface tension of water is ‘S’, the density of water is ‘ρ’ and gravitational acceleration due to earth is ‘g’.

The answer is d= 2S/ρrg. I understand that the solution to this problem equates ρdg and 2S/r, but I need a little verbal reasoning why we equate those two?
Am I correct if I think that basically I have to find till what depth the surface tension of water can withstand the pressure of water underneath? Thanks.

Comment: You can draw free body diagram of the components of surface tension and hydrostatic force...

Answer (score 1):

The force resulting from the pressure of water at depth $d$ on the area $\pi r^2$ is balanced by the force resulting from the surface tension of water along the perimeter $2\pi r$. The pressure will win against the surface tension when
$$d \rho g \times \pi r^2 =  S\times 2 \pi r$$
hence
$$d=\frac{2S}{\rho gr}$$

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way.

The inside of the tube has greater pressure than the atmospheric pressure $P_0$ because of bubble like shape(concave inward). This excess pressure is given by 
$$ P_{excess} = P_0 + \frac{2T}r $$ From there you know the pressure at the same level must be same so,
$$ P_0 + \frac{2T}r = P_0 + \rho gd $$ where $\rho gd $ is the excess pressure at a depth.
Cancelling some terms you get your answer.